# Copy a filtred data in a sheet with xlwings

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, copy-paste, xlwings

I am using xlwings with python 3.7. I want to copy the visible (filtered) data into the 'workload' sheet and paste it into the 'ETP_filtred' sheet.

My code :

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

@xw.sub
def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    sht = wb.sheets['workload']
    sht2 = wb.sheets['ETP_filter']

    for row in sht: 
        if ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].hidden == False:    
            sht2.range('A6').value = row
            sht2.range('A6').options(pd.DataFrame, expand='table').value
```

input :

```
    ID      date           statut     id name    resource
    ABC     03/01/2021     planed          XH         B.K
    BCD     17/01/2021   complete          XH         B.K  
    DEF     20/02/2021     frozen          DN          SG
    CEF     20/02/2021     planed          SN         B.K
```

By filtering for axample (resource = B.K) and (status = planed), I will have as output in sheet 'ETP_filtred':

```
 ID           date           statut     id name    resource    
ABC     03/01/2021           planed          XH         B.K
CEF     20/02/2021           planed          SN         B.K
```